# PHP's gzuncompress function in Java?

Tags: java, php, string, gzip, gzipinputstream

I'm compressing a string using PHP's gzcompress() function:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php

I'd like to take the output from the PHP compression function and decompress the string in Java. Can anyone send me down the right path?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look to [GZIPInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html):

```
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFilename));
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = gzipInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
    // buf contains uncompressed data      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but it might just contain the right info to get you started: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a `ByteArrayInputStream`, then you should be able to decode it with `GZipInputStream`.

To get the bytes out of the String, try `getBytes("ISO-8859-1")`. This encoding won't change the incoming bytes.